# jQuery Multiselect Widget inside a clickable tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget, tooltip, multi-select

I've tried [atooltip](http://itsmeara.com/jquery/atooltip/), which gives me a clickable tooltip and I was able to set a [jQuery UI Multiselector](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/index.htm#basic) as it's content.

```
        jQuery1_9('.fixedHeader tr').first().find('th').first().aToolTip({
          clickIt: true,
          tipContent: '<select class="test" multiple="multiple">' +
                        '<option>Test1</option>' +
                        '<option>Hello</option>' +
                        '<option>1F</option>' +
                      '</select>',
          onShow: function () {
            jQuery1_9(".test").multiselect();
          }
        });
```

However the tooltip always creates and destroys it's content and the multiselector-state won't be saved.

I'm looking for a solution in which I have a tooltip-like functionality with persistent, interactive HTML content.

A popup dialog is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by using [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/).

I'm creating this hidden selector:

```
<select class="test" multiple="multiple">
   <option>Test1</option>
   <option>Hello</option>
   <option>1F</option>
</select>
```

I then call the multiselect operation and hide the whole thing:

```
    $(".test").multiselect()
    $('.ui-multiselect').hide();
    $('.ui-multiselect-close').hide(); // the default close-button is not wanted
```

For the qTip that includes the multiselector widget I then use the following option:

```
    $('.selector').qtip({
        content: {
            text: $(".test").multiselect("widget"), // display the widget
            button: 'Close'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center'
        },
        hide: {
            event: false
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click'
        }
    });
```

The result is a very nice, interactive, small, and tooltip-like window with the jQuery UI Multiselector inside. (Sorry, can't post images, yet.)